# Xamarin forms FreshMVVM: custom styling for side drawer navigation bar

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

Using Xamarin Forms and FreshMVVM to develop a MasterDetailPage cross platform app, I am looking for a way to apply custom styling to the side drawer navigation bar (increase line height, different background color, change font color/size, ...).

Any hints how to achieve that? Thanks in advance.